# JSON Convert to RealObject with RealmList

Tags: xamarin, json.net, xamarin.forms, realm

I'm fetching data from a Server. Until now I converted the data into a simple object model like Company with a collection om Employees. Now hen I introduced  Realm, I changed both Company and Employee to Realm objects, and the Company now have a collection of type RealmList. The issue is that I'm using JSONConvert.Deserialize and it breaks on the collection of Employees as the RealmList. What would the best approach be to fetch the data and convert them to Realm obects? I would like to avoid creating a separate model.

Comment: Can you provide a [simple but complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem, including simplified classes and sample JSON?  Also, what do you mean by **it breaks on the collection of Employees as the RealmList**?  Is an exception being thrown?  If so, can you share the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback, and inner exception?

Comment: This looks like another [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/514). Could you please check that out and see if the workaround works for you?